# How to save results to disk after dask computation?

Tags: python, dask

I have results from a dask delayed computation, which could be a single floating point number, a list of numbers, or a numpy array. Is there a standard `dask` way to save these results to local disk or HDFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dask Delayed wraps Python functions, so you would use whatever Python code you would normally use, but delayed.  Here is an example with JSON

```
def save_data_to_json(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)

L = ... # my list of delayed objects

saves = [dask.delayed(save_data_to_json)(x, filename='myfile.%d.json' % i) 
         for i, x in enumerate(L)]

dask.compute(*saves)
```

If you want to store to something like HDFS then you would use a Python library that supports HDFS, like PyArrow.

You could also convert to a Bag, DataFrame, or Array, and then use their saving functions, which are restricted to data that fits in one of those forms, but are a bit more automatic.